# I have html website folder. I have to load that website dynamically in iframe keeping src attribute empty

Tags: javascript, reactjs, azure, iframe, azure-blob-storage

I have store those file in Azure blob and can access using blob url.
folder structure is like this.
[Folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yi2Ie.png)

If i use the blob url in the Iframe i am able to load website without any trouble.
but i want to load that website without using blob url directly in src attribute of iframe.

i made use of axios to make request to blob url and fetched the data and then write into iframe

```
axios.get("blob_url", {headers:header})
            .then((response) => {
               var html =response.data
               const iframe =document.getElementById("di-fd-frame-xapi")

               iframe.contentWindow.document.open();
               iframe.contentWindow.document.write(html);
               iframe.contentWindow.document.close()
})
```

i am able to fetch content of index.html file and write into the iframe but i am getting blank page.

Pls help in providing solution

1. how can i load this website in iframe
2. is there any other way to load the file in website without exposing the url in iframe.

Comment: What is the benefit of not exposing the url in the frame? In the network view of the browser I will stil see the called url?

Comment: @RaimondKuipers thanks for looking into issues.
actually i can set header while making request and i can control the any request made outside our website.

Comment: Do you see any error in Browser console?

Comment: @HarshitaSingh-MSFT
Yaa "uncaught syntaxerror: unexpected token '<'"

But I can see the index.html content is inside the iFrame body. still page is blank

Comment: This is because HTML is not rendered as text and hence this error is coming.
If you really want to render HTML, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property:

`<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />`
React forces this intentionally-cumbersome syntax so that you don't accidentally render text as HTML and introduce XSS bugs. Please verify if it works, if it does I will post it as an answer.

Comment: Does the below response answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is because HTML is not rendered correctly and hence this error is coming.

If you really want to render HTML, you can use the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` property: `<td dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: html}} />` React forces this intentionally-cumbersome syntax so that you don't accidentally render text as HTML and introduce XSS bugs.